# Regex email validation: one char after @ and before first dot

Tags: regex

I'm looking for proper regex used for email validation

I have following one, tested on https://www.regextester.com/

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&\u2019*+/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$

It works for me with one exception: mail like asdasd@i.ua or asasdasd@p.lodz.pl are correct, but regex dont allow it.
I think because only one char after @ and first dot in domain name.
Do You know how to repair this regex?
I tried many times, but without effect

Comment: See `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+`, two alnum/hyphen chars are required before a `.`. So, just remove `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+`